# how can i use jquery validation in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I use this code in angularjs. I m newly in angularjs please guide to me.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
     form.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery validation in angular. AngularJS provides very nice options for form validations.

Comment: yes i know that but this is my client requirement.

Comment: If you are using angularjs then you should use it's own validation. Otherwise thing will be complicated because jquery call will not be digested by angular. You manually need to digest, that is difficult to manage.

Comment: Yes I know that and that's why I am facing problem but this is my client requirement, what I can do, I have to use j query validation and match up with angularjs, please help its really urgent...